# MS Access First function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have simple MS Access query that i just cant figure out how to replicate in SQL server.

```
 SELECT tbl_XREF_MFG.[ITEM NUMBER], 
 Count(tbl_XREF_MFG.CROSS_REFERENCE) AS CountOfCROSS_REFERENCE, 
 First(tbl_XREF_MFG.CROSS_REFERENCE) AS FirstOfCROSS_REFERENCE
 FROM tbl_XREF_MFG
 GROUP BY tbl_XREF_MFG.[ITEM NUMBER];
```

I know that SQL Server does not have First as function but it has FIRST_VALUE but I can't make it work.  Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT  ([ITEM NUMBER]),
Count(CROSS_REFERENCE) as CountOFCROSS_REFERENCE,
FIRST_VALUE(CROSS_REFERENCE) OVER (ORDER BY CROSS_REFERENCE) as FirstOfCROSS_REFERENCE
INTO #tmp1
FROM tbl_XREF_MFG
GROUP BY ([ITEM NUMBER]),CROSS_REFERENCE
```

How can I get this right?

Comment: why did your group by change?

Comment: It wouldn't let me execute the query if I exclude CROSS_REFERENCE.

Comment: Yeah, don't do that -- no way you will get correct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make this a sub-query.

```
SELECT tbl_XREF_MFG.*,
       FIRST_VALUE(CROSS_REFERENCE) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM_NUMBER ORDER BY CROSS_REFERENCE) AS FIRST
FROM tbl_XREF_MFG
```